# Check if class is derived from a specific class (compile, runtime both answers available)

Tags: c++, class, c++11, encapsulation

It is easier to explain on an example so,

```
class base {
//....
}

class derived1 : public base {
//...
}
```

In my library, there is a pointer of base class. The user of the library have to make classes derived from either base or derived1 and assign pointer to that class.

How can I check what class is user-defined class derived from?

Comment: Runtime or compile time?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Compile time   ....

Comment: For compile time,  you [may want to look here for the trait that can check if X is a base of Y](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631677/174614)

Comment: Are you using C++11? If so  use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: For compile-time, you have [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: In the question title please indicate that you want a compile time check so that it is easily findable and non-repetitive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have some remarks on the proposed compile-time x runtime solutions. In addition to when they are evaluated, `is_base_of` and `dynamic_cast` have different requirements and their answers can be different.

**(1)** First of all (as pointed out by others) to use `dynamic_cast`, base and derived classes must be polymorphic (must have at least one `virtual` method). `is_base_of` doesn't require the types to be polymorphic.

**(2)** The operands of `is_base_of` are both types whereas `dynamic_cast` needs a type (inside `< >`) and an object (inside `( )`).

**(3)** `dynamic_cast` and `is_base_of` can give different answers (or one can compile while the other doesn't) depending on the type of inheritance (`public` vs `protected` or `private`). For instance consider:

```
struct B { virtual ~B() {} }; // polymorphic, so it can be used in a dynamic_cast
struct D1 : public B {};      // polymorphic by (public)  inheritance
struct D2 : private B {};     // polymorphic by (private) inheritance

D1 d1;
D2 d2;
```

We have

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, D1>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, D2>::value, "");

assert(dynamic_cast<B*>(&d1));
assert(!dynamic_cast<B*>(&d2)); // Notice the negation.
```

Actually the last line yields a compiler error in GCC (`error: 'B' is an inaccessible base of 'D2'`). VS2010 does compile it (yielding just a warning similar to GCC's error message).

**(4)** The requirements on the classes being polymorphic can be relaxed through an exception handling trick. Consider:

```
struct B { };             // not polymorphic
struct D1 : public B {};  // not polymorphic
struct D2 : private B {}; // not polymorphic

D1 d1;
D2 d2;

template <typename B, typename D>
const B* is_unambiguous_public_base_of(const D* obj) {
    try {
        throw obj;
    }
    catch (const B* pb) {
        return pb;
    }
    catch (...) {
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Then we have

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, D1>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, D2>::value, "");

assert((is_unambiguous_public_base_of<B>(&d1)));
assert(!(is_unambiguous_public_base_of<B>(&d2))); // Notice the negation.
```

It's worth mentionning that `is_unambiguous_public_base_of` is far slower  than `dynamic_cast` and (this became more obvious after the renaming mentioned in the update below) always returns a `nullptr` for downcasts:

```
B* b1 = &d1;
assert(dynamic_cast<D1*>(b1));        // Requires D1 and B to be polymorphic.
assert(!(is_unambiguous_public_base_of<D1>(b1))); // Notice the negation.
```

A bit outdated reference on this trick is available in the following links:

[Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20130801021123/https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/twisting-the-rtti-system-for-safe-dynami/229401004), [Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140710140948/http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/twisting-the-rtti-system-for-safe-dynami/229401004?pgno=2) and [code](https://web.archive.org/web/20150902163658/http://twimgs.com/ddj/images/article/2011/0411/any_ptr.h/any_ptr.h)

Disclaimer: the implementation of `is_unambiguous_public_base_of` above is just a draft to make the point and it doesn't handle `const` and `volatile` qualifications properly.

**Update**: In a previous version of this post `is_unambiguous_public_base_of` was named `my_dynamic_cast` and this was a source of confusion. So I renamed it to a more meaningful name. (Thanks to Jan Herrmann.)

Comment: Your part 4 is *WRONG* you are casting from a derived to a public base. This works, its only pointer conversion. But you don't cast from a pointer of type `B*` which points to a `D1` to a `D1*`.

Comment: @Jan Herrmann: What exactly is wrong? Yes, using `my_dynamic_cast` to cast from `D1*` to `B*` yields a non NULL ptr (as I said, `assert((my_dynamic_cast<B>(&d1)));` passes). Using it from `D2*` to `B*` yields a NULL ptr (as I said, `assert(!(my_dynamic_cast<B>(&d2)));` passes). Using it for downcasts (contrarilly to `dynamic_cast`) ALWAYS returns a NULL ptr (as I said, `assert(!(my_dynamic_cast<D1>(b1)));` passes). I never said that `is_base_of`, `dynamic_cast` and `my_dynamic_cast` can replace one another. That's the point of my post: to show their differences in semantics and requirements.

Comment: look at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d71f93429fd0abda9911e541a267ca90-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51 I added lines 28 and 29, this is what I would expect from a replacement of `dynamic_cast`. So your part 4 is useless. It does something which can be achieved with simple function overloading (which would result in the same as `static_cast`). So what is its purpose?

Comment: Again, I never said that `my_dynamic_cast` is a replacement for `dynamic_cast` (I agree that I could have chosen a better name though). In addition your test `assert(my_dynamic_cast<D1>(b1));` is exactly the opposite of mine: `assert(!(my_dynamic_cast<D1>(b1))); // Notice the negation.` (See above).

Comment: For use cases, read the reference that I gave in the post. See also slide 27 of this [presentation](http://tinyurl.com/m8f7nsy) by Andrei Alexandrescu where he uses a similar trick.

Comment: Ok I didn't read your post up to the end (I didn't read the last code sample). First I thought I learned something new to exceptions (I read your article, too). But now I know you are right. All your asserts are true. Nevertheless part 4 does contain no code which can not be replaced with `static_cast`. So I think your post suggest something which can not be achieved with C++ or it makes something very complicated with exceptions which can be made easy without. (Now I will look at this viedo.)

Comment: The confusion is mainly due to the name that I have chosen: `my_dynamic_cast`. So I'll update the post to rename it to, say, `my_is_base_of` ;-). Thanks for the discussion anyway.

Comment: Updated again from `is_public_base_of` to `is_unambiguous_public_base_of`. :) For example, if `D : public B,C` and `B : public A` and `C: public A`, then `is_public_base_of<A>(new D)` returns `false`. (See the [dreaded diamond](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-diamond.html).)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [dynamic_cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast).

```
if (dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(ptr)) {
    std::cout << "Class is derived from DerivedClass.";
}
```

Comment: Isn't `dynamic_cast` performs `runtime` check and conversion.

Comment: Yes, it does exactly that.

Comment: But he wants to check it at compiler time. Maybe he should change the title of the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Check if class is derived from a specific class (compile time)

You can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
#include <type_traits>

....

const bool isBase = std::is_base_of<base, TheOtherClass>::value;
```

`isBase` is true if `TheOtherClass` is derived from `base`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this question is **very** difficult. Of course there is `std::is_base_of` and `dynamic_cast`. Both provide you with some very limited information. The third option is function overloading. With all of those techniques you can choose a special path in your code which should be executed.

`std::is_base_of` can be interpreted in a boolean context and it is derived from either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`. This fact makes it possible to use it as paramter for a function and use compile time polymorphism via function overloading. This first example shows how to use it in a boolean context, but you don't have any further specific type information. So compilation will fail in most circumstances ([see here for a further description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807414/c-alternative-to-stdis-fundamental/16811829#16811829)):

```
template<class T>
void do_it1(T const& t) {
  if (std::is_base_of<T,derived1>::value) {
    // we have a derived1 
  } else {
    // we have a base 
  }
}
```

The second version is simple function overloading. Here compile time polymorphism is used but all runtime type information is lost (except virtual functions and `dynamic_cast` are used):

```
void do_it2(Base const& b) {
  // we have a base your algorithm for base here
}
void do_it2(Derived2 const& d) {
  // Derived algorithm here
}
```

Now the third version combines both:

```
template<class T>
void do_it3_impl(T const& t, std::true_type) {
  // here t will be of a type derived from derived1
}

template<class T>
void do_it3_impl(T const& t,std::false_type) {
  // here t will be of type not derived from derived1
}

template<class T>
void do_it_3(T const& t) {
  do_it3_impl(t, std::is_base_of<T,derived1>()); // here we forward to our impl
}
```

The third variant is normaly used for header only libraries which don't use runtime poylmorphism (search for `std::advance` for an excample).

Now to runtime polymorphism. Here you have the `dynaminc_cast` variant:

```
void do_it4(Base const* ptr)
if (derived1 const* obj = dynamic_cast<derived*>(ptr)) {
  // here we have obj with type derived1*
} else {
  // here we have only base
}
```

If this variant is not fast enough you can implement your onw cast to derived1:

```
class derived1;
class base {
  // as above
public:
  virtual derived1 const*  to_derived1() const {
    return 0;
  }
};

class derived1 
   : public base 
{
  // ...
  virtual derived1 const*  to_derived1() const {
    return this;
  }
};

void do_it5(Base const* ptr)
if (derived1 const* obj = ptr->to_derived1() {
  // here we have obj with type derived1*
} else {
  // here we have only base
}
```

This is fast but it scales very well for only **very few** (approximately 1) derived classes.

Last but not least you should think about your class design and deside what methods to make virtual and implement in `base`, `derived1` or other classes. You should definitly  look for [strategy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strategy-pattern).

Comment: I believe that you have to use `std::true/false_type::value` no the type itself.

Comment: @RedXIII thanks, i've changed it (A constructed value should work, too).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will only accept pointers to classes derived from your base class if your library functions takes pointers to the base class. My answer is with a classical approach type safety will handle it. To my experience that kind of type checking is enough. Having 25 years experience in the industry I question the need to do this check. Maybe such a fundamental question is not welcome? I would like to see the justification to having the need to do this kind of upcast. I never have to do that. The opposite, i.e. a down cast I need quite frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways. The most common ones as the others have pointed out are [dynamic_cast<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby9kycs.aspx) and [std::is_base_of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982243.aspx). The latter is used at compile time, while `dynamic_cast<>` can be used at runtime. 
**HOWEVER**, `dynamic_cast<>` will only work **if your source class is polymorphic** (i.e. has at least one virtual function - it can be a method or its destructor). If not, the compiler will trigger an error.