# can templates be used to detect inheritance relationship

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Suppose I have the following code (C++):

```
template < class Td, class Ud, class Vd>
class Extractor
{
private: 
  // some code here
public:
  // the class has functions to populate these vectors
  vector<Td* >    list_of_layers;
  vector<Ud* >    list_of_resistors;
  vector<Vd* >    list_of_nodes;
}
```

I wish to impose the restriction that the classes that are used to replace Td, Ud and Vd while instantiating an object of class Extractor are **ALWAYS derived** from classes (say) T, U and V, respectively. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::is_base_of`, by any chance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if class is derived from a specific class (compile, runtime both answers available)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099241/check-if-class-is-derived-from-a-specific-class-compile-runtime-both-answers-a)

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631689/2567683

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I think std::is_base_of is what I was looking for. I was trying to focus on templates in my search for solution instead of looking for means to verify inheritance.

Thanks Nikos for the related links, they improved my understanding. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `type_traits` and in particular [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) in combination with [`is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) like the example below:

```
#include <type_traits>

class BaseT {};
class BaseU {};
class BaseV {};

class DerivedT : public BaseT {};
class DerivedU : public BaseU {};
class DerivedV : public BaseV {};

template < class Td, class Ud, class Vd, class Enable = void>
class Extractor {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseT, Td>::value, "Template argument Td is not derived from BaseT");
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseU, Ud>::value, "Template argument Ud is not derived from BaseU");
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseV, Vd>::value, "Template argument Vd is not derived from BaseV");
};

template <class Td, class Ud, class Vd>
class Extractor<Td, Ud, Vd, 
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseT, Td>::value &&
                          std::is_base_of<BaseU, Ud>::value &&
                          std::is_base_of<BaseV, Vd>::value>::type> {

};

int main() {
  Extractor<DerivedT, DerivedU, DerivedV> dummy;
  Extractor<int, double, int> dummy2; // will fail to compile!!!
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/556f4c305318194c)

Comment: Nice but the error message in case of type matching failure is pretty misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the live demo and feedback on the question!

@40two: Since I am new to this, can you please explain the code a little bit, as in how the pieces fit together and why (it seems that) we have two definitions of class Extractor?

Comment: @Chatter Actually we don't have two definitions but rather one template definition and one template specialization. When you define an object of type `Extractor` C++ will try to match with the template specialization first. If conditions in `enable_if` are met then "OK Charlie good to go", if the conditions in `enable_if` aren't met (i.e., template arguments aren't derived from specific classes) C++ will try to instantiate an `Extractor` object with provided arguments from `Extractor` definition. However, this will fail due to the `static_assert`s with a specific error message HTH :).

Comment: BTW, `std::enable_if` is useless here, `static_assert` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the `std::is_base_of` trait for that.
Add static assertions to your class, e.g.:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, Td>::value, "Td must inherit from T");
```