# std::is_base_of and error with if

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I've got problem with templates:

I have got two constructors and method:
.cpp:

```
Cell::Cell(sf::Vector2i& uPos, sf::Vector2f& cellDimensions, std::string& stateName)
    :unitPosition(uPos)
{
    setBasicParameters<std::string>(stateName,cellDimensions,uPos);
}

Cell::Cell(sf::Vector2i & uPos, sf::Vector2f & cellDimensions, int stateNumber)
    :unitPosition(uPos)
{
    setBasicParameters<int>(stateNumber,cellDimensions,uPos);
}
```

.hpp::

```
//Basic parameters which are being used by constructors
    template < typename T = typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<int, T>::value, T>::type || typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<std::string, T>::value, T>::type>
    void setBasicParameters(T& object, sf::Vector2f& cellDimensions, sf::Vector2i& uPos);

template<typename T>
inline void Cell::setBasicParameters(T& object, sf::Vector2f& cellDimensions, sf::Vector2i& uPos)
{
    shape.setSize(cellDimensions);
    shape.setOutlineThickness(cellDimensions.x / 10.0f); //10%

    shape.setOutlineColor(constants::cell::FILL_COLOR);

    shape.setPosition(uPos.x*cellDimensions.x, uPos.y*cellDimensions.y);

    if (!StateSystem::isStateExist(object))
    {
        Logger::Log(constants::error::stateSystem::STATE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, Logger::STREAM::BOTH, Logger::TYPE::ERROR);
        state = StateSystem::getNumberOfState(constants::defaults::EMPTY);
    }
    else
    {
        if (std::is_base_of<std::string, T>::value)
            state = StateSystem::getNumberOfState(object);  
        else state = object;

        setColor(StateSystem::getColorOfState(state));
    }
}
```

and problem is there:

```
if (std::is_base_of<std::string, T>::value)
            state = StateSystem::getNumberOfState(object);  
        else state = object;
```

In this if, I check a type of T, and if it is std::string, I use method from StateSystem which changes name to number. In the other way, if T is int, I don't need to change it so I am immediately assign T to state(state is int). But my compiler checks the dwo options and gives me errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'uint8_t'

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'int8_t mv::StateSystem::getNumberOfState(std::string)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'std::string'
```

Can I repair it without do two diffrent methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `if` statement here...

```
if (std::is_base_of<std::string, T>::value)
```

...is a *run-time branch*. Even though `is_base_of` can be evaluated at compile-time, the compiler is forced to compile both branches of the `if` statement, even if their correctness relies on the `is_base_of` condition.

---

> Can I repair it **without two different methods**?

C++17 introduces `if constexpr (...)`, which does the branching at *compile-time*. This still requires both branches to be parseable, but only instantiates the one that matches the predicate. Therefore the non-taken branch can be "invalid" and your program will work as expected.

```
if constexpr (std::is_base_of<std::string, T>::value)
    state = StateSystem::getNumberOfState(object);  
else state = object;
```

If you do not have access to C++14 and you really don't want to use two different functions, you can implement an equivalent construct to `if constexpr(...)`. The implementation requires a significant amount of boilerplate. The final result will look like this:

```
static_if(std::is_base_of<std::string, T>{})
    .then([&](auto){ state = StateSystem::getNumberOfState(object); })
    .else_([&](auto){ state = object; })(_);
```

I gave a talk at [CppCon 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k) and [Meeting C++ 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5II2-cTgNw) called **"Implementing `static` control flow in C++14"** which explains how `static_if` works and how to implement it yourself.

---

If you decide that using two different functions is acceptable, here's how you can solve the issue:

```
if (!StateSystem::isStateExist(object))
{
    // ...as before...
}
else
{
    dispatch(state, std::is_base_of<std::string, T>{});
    // ...as before...
}
```

Where `dispatch` is defined as:

```
void dispatch(State& state, Object& object, std::true_type)
{
    state = StateSystem::getNumberOfState(object);
}

void dispatch(State& state, Object& object, std::false_type)
{
    state = object;
}
```

Comment: Question: what happens with sttic_if that if T is derivative of string. I may imagine that the meet same problem as with static_cast to base class (ending up wiith a temporal?)

Comment: @Swift: sorry but I don't understand what you're asking - can you show a minimal code example? Regardless, `static_if`'s behavior should be equivalent to `if constexpr`, despite the less enticing syntax.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, i have tried with  if constexpr but it gave me 1 new error. I use Visual Studio 2015 Community https://scr.hu/6LXMY6

Comment: @mvxxx: that requires C++17 support - check MSVC compliance on Visual Studio's website

Comment: well i cant  yet figure how to implement it  prior to 14 and video links ( as any other non-textual media) are useless to me

Comment: @Swift: you can't implement it prior to 14, as *generic lambdas* are pretty much mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

`std::is_base_of` is a compile-time thing. You should use it with `static_assert`, for example. Type information at runtime in C++ is something complicated and you should use stuff like RTTI or `dynamic_cast` for it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099241/check-if-class-is-derived-from-a-specific-class-compile-runtime-both-answers-a) gives answers about the difference.