# cache a Base type from template function to use in std::is_base_of<Here!,>

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14, dynamic-cast

I want to create a library that :-

1. User adds callback via `addCallback<Base>(Callback* callback)` (usually at first timestep)
2. Later, usually in a different `.cpp`, whenever user call `actor<Bx>()` :-

   - if `Bx` inherit from `Base`, call `callback->callback()`
   - else do nothing
3. (Information) I know for sure that every `Bx` always inherit from `A`.

Here is the initial code :-

```
#include <iostream>
class A{};
class Callback{
     public: virtual void callback()=0; 
};
template<class Base> void addCallback(Callback* callback){  
    //???
};
template<class Bx> void actor(){
    //???
}
//^^^^^^ my library end here

class B : public A{};
class B1 : public B{};
class C : public A{};
class CallbackCustom1: public Callback{
    public: virtual void callback(){std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;}
};
class CallbackCustom2: public Callback{
    public: virtual void callback(){std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;}
};
int main(){
    CallbackCustom1 call1;
    CallbackCustom2 call2;
    addCallback<A>(&call1); 
    addCallback<B>(&call2); 
    //vvv  below is usually in another .cpp
    actor<B1>(); // should print "A" and "B"
    actor<C>(); // should print "A" only
}
```

How to do it?

## **My poor solutions**

### Solution 1 : std::is_base_of

I really love to use `std::is_base_of<Base,Derive>`.
However, it is impossible because users want to invoke only a single type `Bx` in `actor<Bx>()` for convenience.
`std::is_base_of` need name of two classes not one.

### Solution 2 ([MCVE demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cb34d2e0fb2737c)) : virtual destructor + std::function

It can be optimized more but I want to keep it simple  :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class A{public: virtual ~A()=default; };
class Callback{
     public: virtual void callback()=0; 
};
class MyTuple{public:
    std::function<bool(A*)> func;
    Callback* callback;
};
std::vector<MyTuple> myTuples;
template<class Base> void addCallback(Callback* callback){  
    std::function<bool(A*)> func=
        [](A* a){return dynamic_cast<Base*>(a)!=nullptr;};
    MyTuple tuple; tuple.func=func; tuple.callback=callback;
    myTuples.push_back(tuple);
}
template<class Bx> void actor(){
    Bx b;
    for(auto tuple:myTuples){
        if(tuple.func(&b)){
            tuple.callback->callback();
        }
    }
}
//^^^^^^ my library end here
```

It works, but there are some disadvantages :-

- I have to add **virtual destructor** to `A` to make it **polymorphic**.          I feel that it is a nasty hack.
- In my game, in some time-steps, `A::~A()` is potentially called >100,000 times per seconds.
  I can reduce the cost by make `B1` and `C` **final** and do a batch deletion via derived class, but in some places, it is unsuitable and inconvenient.
- I have to create instance of `Bx` just for the **dynamic_cast** check.
  This may cause some complication if its constructor do something special.

Are there any better way?

Comment: An even worse hack comes to mind: `throw` and `catch` could be abused to test for a public inheritance relationship between non-polymorphic classes at runtime. If you do dare to play with that, you can use some `std::type_index` to cache results and make sure that step is only done once per new type encountered.

Comment: @aschepler  like [Cassio Neri's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100934) in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099241/check-if-class-is-derived-from-a-specific-class-compile-runtime-both-answers-a  ?

Comment: A similar idea, yes, but for your use case, the `throw` and `catch` would need to be in different functions.

Answer (score 1):

Can you require your user to specify the set of allowed `Base` types? In that case the task becomes simple ([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31df4e92e1c8f763)):

```
static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201703L, "example for C++17, but C++14 possible");

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct Callback {
  virtual void callback() = 0;
};

template<class... RegisteredBases>
struct CallbackSystem {

  template<class Base>
  static auto& callbacks_for() {
    static std::vector<Callback*> callbacks_for_base_{};
//
// For each `Base`, the callbacks are stored in a different vector.
// This way, we can avoid the in-loop branch (see `actor_impl`).
//
// TODO: consider performance cost of bad memory locality (can be
// improved if necessary).
//
    return callbacks_for_base_;
  }

  template<class Base>
  static void addCallback(Callback* callback) {
    static_assert((... || std::is_same<Base, RegisteredBases>{}));
    callbacks_for<Base>().push_back(callback);
  }

  template<class Derived, class RegisteredBase>
  static void actor_impl() {// called from `actor` for each RegisteredBase
    if(std::is_base_of<RegisteredBase, Derived>{}) {// branch outside loop
      // if `RegisteredBase` matches then process all its callbacks
      for(Callback* callback : callbacks_for<RegisteredBase>()) {
        callback->callback();
      }
    }
  }

  template<class Derived>
  static void actor() {
    (actor_impl<Derived, RegisteredBases>(), ...);
  }
};
```

The allowed `Base` types are registered like this:

```
using MyCallbacks = CallbackSystem<A, B> {};
```

The usage reads:

```
MyCallbacks::addCallback<A>(&call1);
MyCallbacks::addCallback<B>(&call2);
// MyCallbacks::addCallback<B1>(&call2);// compile error (good)


//vvv  below is usually in another .cpp
std::cout << R"(should print "A" and "B":)" << std::endl;
MyCallbacks::actor<B1>();

std::cout << R"(should print "A" only:)" << std::endl;
MyCallbacks::actor<C>();
```

Alternatively, the API can be designed the other way around: Instead of restricting the `Base` classes one can require the user to specify all classes which are allowed as the template argument of `actor`.

Comment: I stare at the code for a while.  It is hard to test, may you provide some MVCE (e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) ?  It looks useful.  Thanks.

Comment: @cppBeginner: Added link to online demo (see first paragraph of my answer). The singleton-style is probably bad design, but the idea of constrained types can also be applied to a non-singleton: `CallbackSystem<A, B> callbacks{}; callbacks.add_callback<A>(&call1); /* ... pass instance around (by reference)... */ callbacks.actor<C>();`

Comment: In the the first version of your answer (I prefer), users have to do an extra typing.  It is a little error prone and less maintainable.  (It is cleaner and better than CRTP, though.)     In this version, users have to use the *correct* callback to call actor e.g. `CallbackSystem<A, B>::actor()`.  Despite `MyCallbacks` alias, usefulness of callback is reduced.  By the way, I use singleton for simplicity of MCVE.  I don't actually use the pattern.  Thank.  :)

Comment: @cppBeginner: Yes, I agree that the suggestion in my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54337896/1) (where the user had to specify the bases of each class) is error prone. In addition, some level of metaprogramming is required in order to collect those user-provided information. I also agree that the current version is fragile if `CallbackSystem<A, B>::actor<C>()` is used instead of `MyCallbacks::actor<C>();`. Note that this is not an issue if the callbacks are handled in non-singleton instances: `void do_stuff(MyCallbacks& callbacks) { actor<C>(callbacks); }`.